# Resuming Flow after Invocable Future Method

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

Is there a way to resume a Flow after an @Future Apex method is completed? Right now I have an arbitrary Wait element but that's a hack workaround and not reliable of course.

Cross posted in Salesforce Success Community

Comment: is there any user interaction in flow after the wait?

Comment: No. It's an autolaunched Flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the complete terminology of the future methods is that the methods execute asynchronously whenever the resources are available. Which means that it might finish execution in a couple of seconds to even a minute.

As a result, there's nothing that you can do to "resume" the flow. But you can divide the flow in two parts, one that executes before the future method, and the other one that depends on the updates made from the future method. This way both your operations would be performed.